# assigning tool tip to point in mschart (ASP.net C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, mschart

I need to display the value in tool tip on moving the mouse over the data point.It displays the value but value which is displayed in not in proper data point. 
yvalue and axis lable collection is
 (237.71 , 12:13:58 ), 
 (238.53 , 12:28:58),
 (239.95 , 12:58:58 ),
 (238.25 , 1:13:57),
 (240.17 , 1:29:01),
 (241.24 , 1:58:57),
 (243.24 , 2:13:57),
 (243.47 , 2:28:58),
 (242.05 , 2:58:57),
   For example on moving mouse over 237.71 data point it displays 238.53.
and on moving mouse over 241.24 data point it displays 242.05. Please give any suggestion.

```
Chart1.Visible = true;
    string startDate = "", EndDate = "";
    Chart1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(211, 223, 240); //"#D3DFF0"
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.Legends.Add("R Phase");
    Chart1.Series.Add("R Phase");
    Chart1.Series[0].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Time";
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Value";
    Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    Chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 3;
    Chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Maroon;
    Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(AxisLabelGrid1, yValueGrid1);
    Chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
    Chart1.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Auto;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1.0;
    //Chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "#VALX - #VALY";
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var pt in Chart1.Series[0].Points)
    {
        string date = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
       pt.ToolTip = "Value :" + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + "\n Phase : Y Phase";
        if (i == 0)
        {
            startDate = date;
        }
        EndDate = date;
        pt.MarkerColor = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon;
        pt.MarkerSize = 10;
        pt.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
       // pt.ToolTip = "Value :" + pt.YValues[0].ToString() + "\n Phase : R Phase";
        i++;
    }

    Title tit = new Title("Line chart from " + startDate + " to " + EndDate, Docking.Top, new Font("Garamond", 14), Color.Black);
    Chart1.Titles.Add(tit);
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery in your aspx page to add tooltips that way?  It isn't the way you have envisioned it for sure but it may be an easy solution.

Comment: @JasonGeiger thank you for your suggestion. I will try that one too. but what is the mistake in above code?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before.

```
Chart1.Series[0].IsXValueIndexed = false; 
Chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
```

would solve the problem.

Comment: Still i am getting the same result as mentioned above.